# Css Center Aligning A Menu?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in my page. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#head {
    background-image:url(http://manage.smarturl.it/_static/images/homeslice.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font:'BebasNeueRegular';
    border:none;
}
#head {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.style1 {
    font: 27px 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
.style1 li {
    float:left;
}
.style1 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    display:block;
    width:80px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="head">
<img src="logo8bit.png" width="491" height="188" /><br />
<ul class="style1"><li><a href="">LOGIN</a></li><li><a href="">SIGNUP</a></li><li><a href="">OTHER</a></li><li><a href="">MENU</a></li><li><a href="">STUFF</a></li></ul>
</div>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get the menu centrally aligned with margins, because whenever I try to, it messes up how the menu is displayed, and it doesn't show up. Please give me any suggestions you have. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css lik this.

```
.style1{ margin-left:20px;}
.style1 li{ list-style:none; float :left;  padding:5px:}
```

You can increase the margin-left for .style1 and also remove all negative values as its not Gud practice and also I don't think you need to give width manually for anchor tags inside li.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set an explicit width to the `<ul>` element, setting `margin:0 auto;` will center it.

If you don't know the width of the `<ul>`, set the floats to `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left;` and then, for the parent `<ul>`, `text-align:center;`.

Comment: That's if you want to horizontally center the `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>`.